# Reading number of commas in a string not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, console, fgets

I wrote a simple C program for counting the number of commas in a string.
It is a simple console C application done in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

The string is read from a text file but the answer I get is always wrong.

After spending too many hours trying this and that, I am finally posting it here, hoping someone can help me out. I am pasting the code here and
the sample line from the text file. Please take a look at it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
char *myline;
FILE *outputf;
int line_len=4800;
int ncomas=0;
int i=0;    
int coma_count=0;

            outputf = fopen("c:\\tmp\\tmp.csv","r+");
            if (outputf == NULL)
            {
                printf("Couldn't open csv file for writing.\n");                
            }
            else
            {                                               
                myline=(char *)calloc(1,line_len);
                while(fgets(myline,line_len,outputf) != NULL)
                {
                    ncomas=0;
                    for(i=0;i<line_len;i++)
                    {
                        if(myline[i]==',')
                        {
                            ncomas++;
                        }
                    }
                    printf("\nNo of commas is %d\n",ncomas);
                }               
                fclose(outputf);
            }
            return;
}
```

Here is the sample line from file. Actual count is 159 but I am getting 216.

> -1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

Comment: `i<line_len` --> `myline[i] != '\0'`

Comment: Hi folks,Sorry to have troubled you.I just found out the problem.Thanks bluepixy for helping me out.